# Adding IEnumerable<T> to class derived from CollectionBase

Tags: c#, generics, collections

Suppose I have a class TestCollection which is used to hold objects of type Test and is defined as

```
public class TestCollection : CollectionBase
```

This allows me to iterate through the collection either as

```
foreach(object o in collection)
...
```

or

```
foreach(Test t in collection)
```

but does not allow me to use new Linq queries.

If I change the definition of the class to

```
public class TestCollection : CollectionBase, IEnumerable<Test>
```

and add a method

```
public new IEnumerator<Test> GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach (Test o in this.List)
        yield return o ;
}
```

then linq queries are available.

However this new method is not just called for linq queries, but is also called in the legacy code (ie during the foreach(object o in collection) and foreach(Test in Collection).

Is there any difference between the old way of iterating through the collection and this new way assuming all the items in the collection are of type Test? I am aware that adding the IEnumerator method will cause the program to throw an exception if it finds any types other than Test, but want to know if I have overlooked anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will see identical results and only experience a single extra level of indirection (as the new `GetEnumerator` method simply calls the existing `GetEnumerator` method and streams its output).

Answer (score 13):

Since you are in 2.0 (or above), perhaps just inherit from `Collection<T>`?

```
public class TestCollection : Collection<Test> {
    // your extra code here
}
```

Then you get `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` for free, and `virtual` methods that you can `override` to put your stamp on the behaviour.

Comment: Changing a base type is a breaking change - if the class has already shipped, this should not be done.

Comment: If the class has not already shipped, this definitely should be done.

Comment: Didn't want to inherit from Collection<Test> at the moment, because I was hoping to get something for free (or almost free) (ie that needs very little testing.)

Changing to inherit from Collection<T> sounds like quite a big change (ie would need lots of testing).

Also. the actual scenario is more complicated than my example. There will be classes which are derived from Test (say Test2) which have their own collections classes and inheriting Test2Collection from either Collection<Test2> or TestCollection doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

The `IEnumerator<T>` compiled from an iterator doesn't implement the `Reset` method. **EDIT**: I mean that it will throw a `NotImplementedException`.

There's nothing actually wrong with that, but if you want the `Reset` method, you'll have to write your own iterator class, which isn't hard.

Comment: No; it *implements* it - as throwing a `NotImplementedException`. Iterator blocks are fine for this purpose.