# Convert CollectionBase to List or data type usable with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, ienumerator

I am using Aspose cells to manipulate Excel spreadsheets.
One of the types in the API is a collection of Pictures in the spreadsheet, which derives from CollectionBase:

see this link:
http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/aspose.cells.pictures.html

I want to convert this type to something that allows me to use Linq expressions

What are the options for this?

I guess I could iterate over it and manually add it to a `new List<Picture>`
But is there a better way to do this?

I have read this question
[Adding IEnumerable<T> to class derived from CollectionBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468336/adding-ienumerablet-to-class-derived-from-collectionbase)

But I obviously don't have control over the class that implements CollectionBace as it is a third party product

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just use the [`Enumerable.Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method on the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface, which you can do implicitly in a query expression:

```
var query = from Picture picture in pictures
            where ...
            select ...;
```

or explicitly, for instance if you want to use dot notation:

```
var query = pictures.Cast<Picture>()
                    .Where(...)
                    .Select(...);
```

An alternative to `Cast<T>()` is [`OfType<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) - which basically ignores any elements which aren't of the right type. In this case I think `Cast<T>()` is more appropriate though.

If you want to convert the whole collection to a `List<T>` for whatever reason, that's easy too:

```
List<Picture> list = pictures.Cast<Picture>().ToList();
```